Trouble with header with \chapter*{}
UPDATE:  edit the question and the code, as I've been asked to do.
How can I set it up so "Anexos" or "Tablas" appears in my header, whith this code?
\begin{document}
\chapter{Referencias bibliograficas}
\newpage
\chapter*{Anexos}
\section*{Tablas}
\end{document}

My problem is that Latex gives me a header with "Referencias bibliograficas" in the Anexos chapter page. I use this code because I want "Anexos" and "Tablas" unnumbered.
Thanks in advance,
Jorge

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

Don't place \addcontentsline before \chapter*, it should go after. Also it does not touch the headers, you need \markboth{}{} or \markright{} for that.

Note: I'm asking for a MWE, because the answer depends a lot on, i.e., the class you are using. For example with KOMA-Script's book class scrbook you could simply use \addchap instead of fiddling with \addcontentsline and \markboth. Or if the chapter is in the front matter, you can simply use \chapter instead of \chapter* etc.

Thanks for the answers. It was solved with \markboth
